# Quitting Braid causes dual monitors to switch to mirror mode

Tags: 11.10, xorg, display, radeon, fullscreen

I have 2 monitors in my desktop. The one has a smaller resolution than the other (don't know if it matters for this issue). From *Display* I have disabled mirroring, so the first monitor continues to the other.

Today I installed Braid. When I launch it, it goes fullscreen. When I quit the game, the setting have reverted to the mirroring of monitors (and with the smaller resolution), and I have to set them up each time.

Is there a solution for that?

The GPU is **sapphire radeon hd 3870**, haven't install any extra drivers for the GPU, **64bit** CPU, using **gnome-shell**

---

The output of xrandr

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2464 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 228mm
   1024x768       60.0*+   75.1     75.0     70.1  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DIN disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected 1440x900+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 257mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Comment: The GPU is ATI. 64bit CPU. Anything else?

Comment: Add it to your question, comments get buried here. If you know the exact model that might help too.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you run in windowed mode? `/opt/braid/braid -windowed -width 1024`

Comment: @kikixx Sorry for the delay. No when I run it in windowed mode, it's ok. So the problem rises with the fullscreen I guess. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried it with my monitor, and it turned off the secondary monitor on starting braid. Quitting braid did not turn on it either, and I had to do it in Displays manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have braid myself but have found this issue [else where](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=16278). What I can only suggest is two workarounds:

1) run in windowed mode, as detailed in comments above, which sounds like it works.

2) create a new launch script as detailed on the WINEHQ page linked above, to use xrandr after braid quits to return the correct resolution.
`/opt/braid/braid && xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1024x768 && xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1440x900`

*edit: changed suggested `xrandr` command to match OP output*

Comment: I put the output of xrandr in the first post. Could you help me for the command mentioned above? Thx :)

Comment: I managed to make it work with `/opt/braid/braid && xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1024x768 && xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1440x900 --right-of DVI-0` Thx :)